# How to prove that the vector space of all $n \times n$ matrices is the direct sum of the vector spaces of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

From Linear Algebra 5th edition, by Stephen H. Friedberg, Arnold J. Insel, and Lawrence E. Spence, section 1.3, page 23:

> 28. A matrix $M$ is called skew-symmetric if $M^t = -M$. Clearly, a skew-symmetric matrix is square. Let $F$ be a field. Prove that the set $W_1$ of all skew-symmetric $n \times n$ matrices with entries from $F$ is a subspace of $M_{n \times n}(F)$. Now assume that F is not of characteristic two (see page 549), and let $W_2$ be the subspace of $M_{n \times n}(F)$ consisting of all symmetric $n\times n$ matrices. Prove that $M_{n\times n}(F) = W_1 \bigoplus W_2$.

(definition of direct sum):

> **Definition.** *A vector space $V$ is called the **direct sum** of $W_1$ and $W_2$ if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}$ and $W_1+W_2=V$.*

(definition of sum):

> **Definition.** *If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are nonempty subsets of a vector space $V$, then the **sum** of $S_1$ and $S_2$, denoted $S_1 + S_2$, is the set ${x+y:x\in S_1 \text{ and } y\in S_2$*

I can prove that $W_1$ is a vector space, but how do I prove that $M_{n\times n}(F) = W_1 \bigoplus W_2$?

Comment: Hint, the matrices with only one nonzero entry form a basis of $M_{n\times n}(F)$.  So it's enough to show how you can write those kind of matrices as a linear combination of a symmetric and skew-symmetric matrix.  Try writing some examples for $n=3$, say.

Comment: @JairTaylor Sorry, I haven't learned about bases and linear combinations yet.

Comment: Another approach is: given $A$, consider the two matrices $A+ A^T$ (symmetric) and $A-A^T$ (skew-symmetric) and see if you can figure out how to write $A$ in terms of those.

Comment: Have you seen that every function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the sum of an odd and an even function? Pretty much the same idea here.